# Exchange elements of a java matrix

Tags: java, matrix

What I want is a program that given 4 entries, that is, two rows and two columns, exchange those elements.
That is, from the matrix

```
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
9 10 11 12
```

if I enter 11 22 the output would be the matrix exchanged those positions (I start the index at 1 and not 0).
Out:

```
6  2  3  4
5  1  7  8
9 10 11 12
```

The code that I have:

```
public static int[][] change(int[][] matrix, int size, int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2) {
    int x;

    x = matrix[x1][x2];
    matrix[x1][x2] = matrix[y1][y2];
    matrix[y1][y2] = x;

    return matrix;
}
```

Comment: Well if you start at index 1, you have to reflect this in your code as well.

Comment: So, what's the issue?  Is it producing the off by 1 errors as listed, or is there something else wrong?  I can't find the question in your question

Comment: I have that method and then another one that prints it and does not change the columns, that's what I was referring to.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are start at 0 with their index. *If* `1` is supposed to access the first value you have to compensate that offset:

```
public static int[][] change(int[][] matrix, int size, int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2) {
    int x;
    x1--; x2--; y1--; y2--;

    x = matrix[x1][x2];
    matrix[x1][x2] = matrix[y1][y2];
    matrix[y1][y2] = x;

    return matrix;
}
```

Comment: I do not get it. I have that method and then another one that prints it and does not change the columns, that's what I was referring to.

Comment: I have an edge in the matrix, so it is indifferent. anyway the result does not, print the same matrix.

Comment: @FernandoBenavidel that frankly does not concern me. This code exchanges two values. You have not shown how you create an array, pass it into the method, pass it into printing or what the printing looks like. And you should not do that in this question because it is another topic. You should start **debugging** your code.

Comment: I already have the code quite well refined, with its methods, calls and variables well defined, so out there I do not see any problem.

Answer (score 2):

so you simply want another method that solves all? I am in a good mood so there:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        if (args.length != 2 ) {
          System.out.println("two arguments required")
        } else {
          int x1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) / 10 -1;
          int x2 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) % 10 -1;
          int y1 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]) / 10 -1;
          int y2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]) % 10 -1;
          change(matrix, x1, x2, y1, y2);    
        }
      }
```

I leave you variable initialization and catching invalid to hone your java skills :)

Comment: I need something in general, not just diagonals, but any element of the matrix.

Comment: and how exactly this one would not swap non - diagonally placed ones?

Comment: I already have the keyboard input. I need the method that exchanges the elements of the matrix. I made that method but it does not print the matrix. I have a separate method to print the matrix in the main.